# Backbone Pageable Collection how to override the queryparams value

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-paginator

I am using backbone paginator plugin (server mode) in my web app. This plugin speaks to server in terms of pages. For example, to get results for page 5, it gives a request as below (taken from paginator server example: http://backbone-paginator.github.io/backbone.paginator/examples/server-mode.html)

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?page=5&per_page=15&...
```

But my server accepts count and offset values instead of page and per_page. So, I have to convert

```
"page=5" to "offset=76" (assuming page size is 15).
```

Similarly

```
"per_page=15" becomes "count=15".
```

So, the modified request should look like,

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?offset=101&count=15&...
```

I could change the names of parameters using the "queryParams" hash.  But could not figure out how to change the page=5 to offset=76.

I thought I should override get*page methods, but there I don't get access to query parameters.

Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it is a little bit late, but you could try overriding queryParams

```
 queryParams: {
     currentPage: "page",
     pageSize: "offset"
 }
```

and state

```
state: {
        firstPage: 0,
        pageSize: 20
    }
```

Of course, you can override additional parameters from backbone.paginator.js if you like

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `state`'s `currentPage` value with a function that returns the multiplication of the `pageSize`.

Note that [the docs](http://backbone-paginator.github.io/backbone.paginator/api/#!/api/Backbone.PageableCollection-property-state) state that:

> […] You should only override this value during extension, initialization or reset by the server after fetching. This value should be read only at other times.

You should probably also override the `parseState` function, to accept the values returned from the backend correctly. Check out [the docs](http://backbone-paginator.github.io/backbone.paginator/api/#!/api/Backbone.PageableCollection-method-parseState) for further information.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own version of  page state management by reverting back to backbone.collection.